# Source for not sewing on Motzei Shabbos

Tags: minhag, motzei-shabbos

I know people that do not sew anything on Motzei Shabbos. What is the source for this Minhag?

Comment: Hi Earl. Did you try asking them? What did they say?

Comment: No. They would probably say that is what my mother did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minhag of refraining from  sewing  on motzei shabbas goes under the umbrella of women not doing melachos gedolos (defined by poskim). Rav Belsky in Shulchan HaLevi explains why sewing is singled out as the common custom.He explains that a woman knows how to sew in a proper (uman) fashion ,opposed to a man who sews like a hedyot (not an expert). Do they took on the custom to refrain of doing a maaseh uman,but only up until chatzos.

The Rivevos Ephraim 2:115:107 brings down many sources(Aruch Hashulchan says we go with the Yerushalmi which says its not a minhag,rather after havdalah melacha can be done) but ends off saying that sewing is the one melecha he knows ppl are machmir on as opposed to other meleachos.

Text of Shulchan HaLevi:

[image]

Text of Rivevos Ephraim:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A source that I am aware of is the [Mogen Avraham 299:15](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14325&st=&pgnum=88&hilite=) who mentions in the name of the Avudraham that woman have a Minhag to refrain from doing work on Motzai Shabbos.

Comment: The Yerushalmi (Pesachim 4:1) says explicitly this is not a Minhag (as in, even though some people do it it doesn't have the status of Minhag).  נשיי דנהיגין דלא למיעבד עובדא באפוקי שובתא אינו מנהג.

Comment: @DoubleAA: Avudraham says Nahagu Hanashim

Comment: The Tur writes the samme loshon when talking about the bracha of שעשני כרצנו

Comment: I'm curious if there is any connection between this minhag (or whatever you wish to call it) and the act of the women sewing the curtains for the Mishkan. Offhand, I'm not sure what the connection might be, but, maybe there is something?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this in tamei haminhagim years ago. The reason given there is because that is the time that tachrichim were traditionally sewn.